# Ubuntu 17.10 can't ping a server, which was a home network previously

Tags: 17.10, ping

I have a mystery problem after upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10:  All works ok, then I go to University with my laptop, work there, connected to the local network, then I come home and cannot browse even the public University web-site:  http://www.manchester.ac.uk/ ,  it gives the error: www.manchester.ac.uk’s server DNS address could not be found. Other sites work ok.  Ping gives: 
ping: www.manchester.ac.uk: Name or service not known

This problem disappears after computer reboot,  but not after the restart of network service. Other computers connected to the same Wi-Fi router  can resolve this site. 
Somehow, it looks as Ubuntu 17.10 remembers that this site was within my home network and does not try to look up for it properly.

Comment: The problem seem to have disappeared without cure. Probably, some update have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me, at the University of Southampton. After disconnecting from the university network and connecting to home Wi-Fi, I cannot browse some university-related webpages, I cannot connect to VPN, and Thunderbird fails to connect to the university e-mail account.

The problem appeared after the upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10 and is resolved with a reboot. Before reboot, `cat /etc/resolv.conf` gives

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search Home soton.ac.uk
```

whereas, after reboot, it gives

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
search Home
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue (also when moving from a *.ac.uk domain to a home wireless).  I can fix without rebooting by commenting out the equivalent line to

```
search Home soton.ac.uk
```

and restarting the network manager:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

This is still a pain though.